# Are there any free emoji fonts?

Tags: icon, glyphs, font-recommendation

I want to use Unicode emoji icons ([U+1F300..U+1F5FF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_And_Pictographs)) in a free, open-source instant messaging app. I considered using [*FontAwesome* icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/), but their icon set is too small (not enough faces for `:)`, `:O`, `:P`, etc.).
Then I wanted to use *Segoe UI Emoji*, but that's copyrighted and expensive, as it's owned by Microsoft.

**Are there any free Emoji-complete fonts? If so, what are they?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a [shopping question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/215485)

Comment: I know it's SO policy, but on newer, experimental technologies, these types of Q and A help a lot of people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open sans emoji should work

Here is a link to a github repo 
https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji

Comment: Looks great. Any idea where someone could see a sample before installing the font?

Comment: This one doesn't have some glyphs that other font packages have, such as **Symbola** and **Noto Emoji**.

Answer (score 20):

Google's TrueType fonts

- [Noto Emoji](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#emoji-zsye) (284.4 KB)

and

- [Noto Color Emoji](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#emoji-zsye-color) (6.5 MB)

are very good.

Comment: neat font but how can I create .woff format?

Comment: @AiShiguang Download from https://www.google.com/get/noto/#emoji-zsye-color.

Comment: I get an error that literally bars me from using the Noto Color Emoji font on Mac OS Big Sur 11.2.1. Interestingly the monochrome version works fine.

Comment: Note that Blink (Chromium/Chrome/Opera/Vivaldi/Brave) does NOT support colored icons as a web font: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=306078

Comment: These families have been combined and are now hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji). Download [here](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/raw/main/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf).

Answer (score 12):

<s>I know this question is a bit old but no one mentioned [Emoji One](http://emojione.com/)</s>

It's CC-BY 4.0.

As of version 3 they are no longer CC BY 4.0...
You can still [download the last version 2.2.7 commit here](https://github.com/emojione/emojione/archive/v2.2.7.zip) but it's from 2016........

Comment: It was maybe but now only a free version + paid licenses and no OpenSource version

Answer (score 5):

We should mention [Symbola](http://www.fontspace.com/unicode-fonts-for-ancient-scripts/symbola) as perhaps the most free and complete face.  It now has over 7000 glyphs including a complete range of Unicode code points from 0x1F300 to 0x1F6FF.

Comment: Hi Cedric, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: That's a nice one! I like the design of them, too!

Comment: BTW If it's more efficient to install as a system font rather than limit to a single app, the face is packaged for Debian/Ubuntu as `ttf-ancient-fonts`.

Comment: The `ttf-ancient-fonts` package includes the `fonts-symbola` package. You can install straight the `fonts-symbola` package.

Comment: This one is missing some glyphs found in **Noto Emoji**.

Answer (score 4):

Twitter has open-sourced [their emojis on Github](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji).

Answer (score 3):

This looks like what you want: http://emojisymbols.com/

> - This is a Web font specialized for use on the Internet.
> - The font can
>     be used free of charge for Web pages and Web services, be it for
>     private or business use.
> - The font can be uploaded to your Web server
>     for use.

Comment: Hi JHS, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I'm looking for one to use in a desktop application. Thanks, though!

Comment: It's not really free: You're not allowed to subset it (unless you pay), which makes it of little use for websites.

Comment: It is also very incomplete (now).

Comment: @Crissov agreed, I would go with the Google emoji fonts since those will be kept up to date. (Or EmojiOne / anything updated with the current Unicode points)

Answer (score 2):

If you need monochrome emoji characters only, consider using the [**Emoji icon font**](https://github.com/jslegers/emoji-icon-font) or [**EmojiSymbols font**](http://emojisymbols.com/).

Alternatively, consider creating your own icon font using the [**Icomoon app**](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select).

Answer (score 1):

There's a useful font I have on my computer from Adobe called Emoji One. I think you can get it from this link (Github) https://github.com/adobe-fonts/emojione-color
Try via Adobe Fonts as well. I don't remember how I personally got it.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has a font called [twemoji](https://twitter.github.io/twemoji/). See [Open sourcing Twitter emoji for everyone](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/a/2014/open-sourcing-twitter-emoji-for-everyone)

In fact Firefox also includes it by default. Since version 50.0 Firefox has already [embedded its own renderer and font](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/50.0/releasenotes/) for supporting colored emoji on unsupported platforms. Originally it used [EmojiOne](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/emojione-color) and later it [switched to Twemoji](https://github.com/mozilla/twemoji-colr/releases/tag/v0.3.1)

You can find the font file in `%FirefoxInstallDir%\fonts\`. Previously it was `EmojiOneMozilla.ttf` and nowadays it's `TwemojiMozilla.ttf`

Answer (score -1):

Try [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/)

It's not strictly for Emojis, but you basically create your own icon font by combining many pre-defined fonts or you can upload your own SVGs.

Comment: I was hoping to find a font that's already drawn all 533 Unicode emoji glyphs... thank you anyway